# How to append another cookie object in existing cookie using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I want to store new object in existing cookie so that I will have old object as well as **new object in cookie**.

For example:

```
$cookieStore.put("myApp", $user); //this is old object
```

Now, I want to add new object and at the same time also want this old object in my cookie.

```
//New object

$cookieStore.put("myApp", $Developer);
```

I want both objects in my cookie.

Could anyone please tell how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's Quite simple, you can do this by making array of objects of your cookies object.

```
var objArr = [];
objArr.push($user);
objArr.push($Developer);
$cookieStore.put("myApp", objArr);
```

You can make this thing dynamic..

```
var objArr = [];
function addCookies(obj){  
  objArr.push(obj);
}

addCookies(YourCookiesObj); //call function by passing your cookies obj ($User, $Developer)
```

Comment: great! It will be helpful.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do up, if it is helpful

Comment: Surjeet, can you tell me how to add this 'objArr' (which has multiple objects stored in it) into angularjs service? I am doing something like this:

myService.addUser($scope.objArr); 

but it's not working. It says $scope.objArr is undefined.

//Service:
myApp.service('myService', function($cookieStore) {
    var user = $cookieStore.get("myApp");

    var addUser = function(newObj) {
        user = newObj;
  
    };

    var getUser = function(){
 
        return user;
    };
 
    return {
        addUser: addUser,
        getUser: getUser,

    };

});

Comment: @RCN, Because objArr is not in your Scope. So you can not access it through $scope.objArr . You can do this by passing just objArr into your service. Like myService.addUser(objArr)